# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in layout/activity_main

Tags: java, android

I found that if I run my code with Android version 34 it works perfectly, while if I run it with version 33 it gives me the following errors, maybe it's a question of displaying the fragments based on the size of the device

Can you help me please

```
package com.example.prova;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.prova.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.example.prova.model.SidRepository;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String TAG = "AppM";
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private String sid;
    private int uid;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        SidRepository.initSid(this, (sid, uid) -> {
            this.sid = sid;
            this.uid = uid;
            Log.d(TAG, "MainAct - SID: " + this.sid + " MainAct - UID: " + this.uid);
            checkLocationPermission();
        }, t -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Sid non ottenuto");
        });

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_objects_list, R.id.navigation_ranking, R.id.navigation_user).build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }

    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            requestLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        // Implement your logic to handle location updates here
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // Permission denied by user
                // Show an error message explaining why the location permission is needed
                showPermissionDeniedDialog();
            } else {
                // Permission granted or request cancelled, proceed with location updates
                requestLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showPermissionDeniedDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permessi necessari")
                .setMessage("Per accedere a questa funzionalità, è necessario concedere i permessi di posizione.")
                .setPositiveButton("Impostazioni", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Apri le impostazioni dell'applicazione per concedere i permessi manualmente
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Annulla", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the error, I try to find something but I don't find anything

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.example.prova, PID: 3917
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prova/com.example.prova.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.prova:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.prova:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.prova:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.prova:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.example.prova:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.prova:id/password_toggle with resource ID #0x7f080178
                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.prova:id/password_toggle" (7f080178) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=7 r=0x7f080178}
                    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:824)
                    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:669)
                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1002)
                    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:992)
                    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:931)
                    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:906)
                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.k(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:41)
                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ab.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:98)
                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ck.aE(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:29)
                    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ef.d(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:13)
                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.s.bp(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:159)
                    at m.bay.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@234910201@234910200049.587833741.587833741:21)
                    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1164)
                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:2)
                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzl.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:3)
                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzah.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:3)
                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zac.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zaa.onDelegateCreated(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:3)
                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzai.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:5)
17:49:26.665  E     at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzai.createDelegate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:1)
                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:6)
                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.1.0:1)
                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.2.0:4)
                    at com.example.prova.ui.Home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:41)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
                    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
```

I hope that work with both version

Comment: Look at the View with id `password_toggle` on the other fragments. The stack trace contains a line as: `Resource "com.example.prova:id/password_toggle" (7f080178) is not a Drawable`.